# Python pywinauto enter symbols or raw key entry

Tags: python, sendkeys, pywinauto

I'm using `pywinauto` `sendkeys` to enter some data into a window. I have symbols like `% ^ ! +`. As `sendkeys` uses it was hotkeys for some keys in windows os I wan't to enter this symbols ignoring the hotkeys. It don't need to press hotkeys at this symbols. Please help me out.

Comment: Thanks for the question. It needs to be mentioned in the docs. Will add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could be unescaped by `{}` as I remember. Like this:

```
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
send_keys("{%}{!}{^}")
```

will print out: `%!^`

Comment: Actually i'm not catching any element or windows I just want raw key entries. Any how I'm using another package. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: OK, I've corrected the answer to remove binding to specific element. Is that working for you?

Comment: Yeah Thanks! As is said I have used another package. But it was an answer for my question.